# Click all checkboxes on a webpage with HTML script (quickbooks/Safar)

Tags: javascript, html, quickbooks

So I created the following script to select all check boxes on a page

```
(function(d) {
  var input = d.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var i = input.length;

  while (i--) {
    input[i].checked = true;
  }
})(this.document);
```

It does work to do that, however when trying it in **Quickbooks** while it does select all the boxes, the website does not register it as actually being selected (the total cost at the bottom remains the same, its like it superficially checks the boxes, visually only with no actual register). Any help would be great.

EDIT: Maybe simulating a click instead of changing the box values?

[The only thing that changes when physically selecting a box is the value posted below changes to true from false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS3fV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should do :

```
input[i].setAttribute("checked", "");
```

The **checked** attribute is a boolean attribute, so the standard way to add it to an element is to pass an empty string for value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute#Exemple